# Transpile to ES5 corrupt JS library in Angular 6 project

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, ecmascript-5, tsconfig

I am trying to use Dygraph library in an Angular 6 project. It works perfectly in Chrome / FF, however it does not work in IE11. I installed the library through npm, and installed the @types from https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/dygraphs

I imported the library in my module using:

```
import { default as Dygraph } from 'dygraphs';
```

When I open the page on IE11, loading stops on:

```
this.xticks.push({pos, label, has_tick});
```

With error `SCRIPT1003: Expected ':'.`. The block where it stops loading is:

```
    DygraphLayout.prototype._evaluateLineTicks = function() {
      var i, tick, label, pos, v, has_tick;
      this.xticks = [];
      for (i = 0; i < this.xTicks_.length; i++) {
        tick = this.xTicks_[i];
        label = tick.label;
        has_tick = !('label_v' in tick);
        v = has_tick ? tick.v : tick.label_v;
        pos = this.dygraph_.toPercentXCoord(v);
        if ((pos >= 0.0) && (pos < 1.0)) {
          this.xticks.push({pos, label, has_tick});    <<--- This line stops
        }
      }

      this.yticks = [];
      for (i = 0; i < this.yAxes_.length; i++ ) {
        var axis = this.yAxes_[i];
        for (var j = 0; j < axis.ticks.length; j++) {
          tick = axis.ticks[j];
          label = tick.label;
          has_tick = !('label_v' in tick);
          v = has_tick ? tick.v : tick.label_v;
          pos = this.dygraph_.toPercentYCoord(v, i);
          if ((pos > 0.0) && (pos <= 1.0)) {
            this.yticks.push({axis: i, pos, label, has_tick});
          }
        }
      }
    };
```

By looking at the original js file, we can observe that the keys have been removed during compilation. Functions in the original file:

```
DygraphLayout.prototype._evaluateLineTicks = function () {
  var i, tick, label, pos, v, has_tick;
  this.xticks = [];
  for (i = 0; i < this.xTicks_.length; i++) {
    tick = this.xTicks_[i];
    label = tick.label;
    has_tick = !('label_v' in tick);
    v = has_tick ? tick.v : tick.label_v;
    pos = this.dygraph_.toPercentXCoord(v);
    if (pos >= 0.0 && pos < 1.0) {
      this.xticks.push({ pos: pos, label: label, has_tick: has_tick });
    }
  }

  this.yticks = [];
  for (i = 0; i < this.yAxes_.length; i++) {
    var axis = this.yAxes_[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < axis.ticks.length; j++) {
      tick = axis.ticks[j];
      label = tick.label;
      has_tick = !('label_v' in tick);
      v = has_tick ? tick.v : tick.label_v;
      pos = this.dygraph_.toPercentYCoord(v, i);
      if (pos > 0.0 && pos <= 1.0) {
        this.yticks.push({ axis: i, pos: pos, label: label, has_tick: has_tick });
      }
    }
  }
};
```

I do not understand why a working library get converted into a non working file. My tsconfig.json file is untouched:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Would someone have any clue ?

Comment: `{pos, label, has_tick}` is ES6 syntax, which is not supported in IE11.  Perhaps you aren't transpiling to ES5 properly?  You could also hand edit that line to `{pos:pos, label:label, has_tick:has_tick}` which is the same data structure in ES5 syntax, but if your code is using ES6 features and you aren't transpiling to ES5 properly, then there are probably other areas in the code that will have problems too so you probably need to fix the transpiling settings.

Comment: The library by default has {pos:pos, label:label, has_tick:has_tick}. But for some reasons the code got transpiled to ES6 but I cannot figure out why. All the Angular / CoreUI components works, only this library is causing problem. Maybe it is related to the way I import it ?

Comment: That confirms it is your transpiling config settings which is actually converting working ES5 code to ES6+ code. I don't really know TypeScript config, but why is `lib` set to "es2017".  You appear to be transpiling to ES2017, when you probably want to transpile to "ES5".

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that, as recommended by jfriend00, the configuration needed to be:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es5",
      "es6",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

What does lib does is not that clear in the documentation, but it seems that it should list the formats from all source codes to be compiled.

As I have DOM, ES5 and ES6 code, I needed all of them. The template I used only contained only DOM/ES6 code, that is probably why the lib was set to DOM/ES2017 only.