# Angular CLI remove arrow functions?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to get my code running on IE11, however, I am having issues with arrow functions. I cannot figure out how to remove them from the build and replace them with `function() {}`.

It looks like they were removed from my `main.js`, but in the `vendor.js` file, the arrow functions still persist. How can I remove them?

I have a browserslist that looks like this:

```
> 0.5%
last 2 versions
Firefox ESR
not dead
IE 9-11
```

I also have a `tsconfig.json` that looks like this:

```
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "downlevelIteration": true,
        "importHelpers": true,
        "outDir": "../path/to/folder",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "typeRoots": [
            "node_modules/@types"
        ],
        "lib": [
            "es2017",
            "dom"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe your tsconfig should be targeting es2015, then when you build production, it should generate legacy es5 bundles that won't include arrows or any es6 features. https://angular.io/guide/deployment#differential-loading

Comment: @DamianC doing that does create a legacy build, however, es6 arrow functions still exist in the file.

Comment: Can you share an excerpt and file name of an es5 bundle with an arrow function? Also can you post the production section of your angular.json

Comment: Are you using external js library containing arrow functions? The CLI does not transpile Javascript code. Third-party code is expected to be in the appropriate format. Besides, you could also refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51523018/transpile-to-es5-corrupt-js-library-in-angular-6-project), set `lib` to `"es5", "es6", "dom"` to see if it works.

Comment: Yeah the third party code does have arrows

Comment: So you should use an ES5 version of the library. If there's no ES5 version of the library, then the only option you have is to transpile it to ES5 by yourself using babel or something else.

Comment: Is there a transpiler that I can use with angular?

Comment: I think you can't transpile it directly in angular. You can just transpile it first with [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) or manually modify it. But the library should be provided already transpiled or have both es6 and es5 version, if not I strongly recommend you raise an issue with the author or create a PR to help fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `"files"`, `"include"`, and `"exclude"` properties in your `tsconfig.json` to specify which files to compile. I'm pretty sure it won't touch `.js` files by default.
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#examples
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#details

Comment: what will happen to `vendor.js` that angular/webpack generates?

Comment: In most cases you should avoid making changes like this to the tsconfig as the cli makes a few assumptions about what your typescript config will be.

Answer (score 0):

One of my vendor dependencies "debug" contained arrow functions ([view source](https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/blob/master/src/browser.js#L156)). These dependencies are not transpiled and thus IE11 cannot parse the js file.

In my case I reverted the offending package back to an older version. eg. package.json

```
"debug": "^3.2.6",
```

To find the offending dependency serve your angular application as ES5 and use the IE11 developer tools to pinpoint the line the js file breaks at. This will give you a clue as to what npm package it is. You can then use `npm ls` to map the dependency tree of the package.