# SCRIPT1002 Syntax Error in vendor.js - Angular 8 IE11

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, internet-explorer-11

Trying to get Angular to work in IE 11. I tried everything I found on the web already.

I'm getting the following errors:

> SCRIPT1002: Syntax error
>
> File: vendor.js, Line: 110874, Column: 40

Line 110874

```
args[0].replace(/%[a-zA-Z%]/g, match => {
    if (match === '%%') {
        return;
    }
    index++;
    if (match === '%c') {
        // We only are interested in the *last* %c
        // (the user may have provided their own)
        lastC = index;
    }
});
```

I have already made the recommended es5 configurations indicated by the angle and I am running with these configurations (https://angular.io/guide/deployment Configuring serves for ES5).

My polyfills.ts:

```
/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for the Reflect API. */
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.
```

My tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "importHelpers": true,
        "target": "es2015",
        "typeRoots": [
            "node_modules/@types"
        ],
        "lib": [
            "es2018",
            "dom"
        ]
    }
}
```

My tsconfig.es5.json:

```
{
    "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5" 
     }
   }
```

I'm using angular 8 and primeng;
And I run with ng serve -- configuration es5;

**Update**:
From what I discovered the problem occurs with the dependencies of the socket-io-client I am using. Researching a little it seems that the problem has to do with the socket-io-client's debug and babel dependencies. I really need to use the socket on my system so I am still looking for a solution. But if I remove the socket-io-client it will run normally.

I found the source of the problem through these two topics:

> https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/729
>
> https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/10707

Comment: The vendor file is other node_modules files that are not transpiled. I think the code comes from a debug from babel or similar. You either have to turn debug off or remove the library. For example see this https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/701

Comment: Also note that `"target": "es2015"` Will produce code the Internet Explorer doesn't support.

Comment: @aluanhaddad I make a tsconfig.es5.json with target in es5 and i run with this configuration. Do you still need to change tsconfig.json?

Comment: No, as long as that's the file that's being used by webpack When you're getting these errors Then that's fine.

Comment: @peterS If that's the case, the problem is complicated because I don't use babel directly, but some libraries I use depend on it.

Comment: It is complicated yes as a file you are requesting is a support file is not compatible with IE11. Either remove the dependency, choose a lower version of the file, or change a library -- or as the link shows transpile a node_module entry (undesirable)

Answer (score 2):

The issue is arrow functions not being transpiled successfully. Have you followed the steps in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58380976/angular-8-using-async-pipe-for-internet-explorer-11/58387761#58387761) to support Angular 8 in IE 11? If you have followed the steps and the problem still persistes, it might because you used external js library containing arrow functions.

Angular CLI doesn't transpile Javascript code. Third-party code is expected to be in the appropriate format. You should use an ES5 version of the library to make it compatible with IE 11.

You could also refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51523018/transpile-to-es5-corrupt-js-library-in-angular-6-project), set `lib` to `"es5"`, `"es6"`, `"dom"` to see if it works. If not working, just use an ES5 library version.

---------------------------------------------------------------------Edit-------------------------------------------------------------

You could use `exclude` property in `webpack.config.js` or `babel.config.js` to transpile modules. We could change this:

```
...
  exclude: /node_modules/,
...
```

into this:

```
...
  exclude: /node_modules\/(?!name-of-untranspiled-module)/,
...
```

Reference: [How to handle npm modules which include es6](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/171)

Comment: Yes, I am already using a configuration, apparently it is a problem in the dependencies of my libraries.

Comment: OK, then you need to change the libraries to make them compatible.

Comment: I cant change. I updated a description of the problem. It seems to be a problem with socket-io-client babel and debug dependencies. I need to use socket-io-client in the version I'm using, if I go back many versions it works but I lose a lot of resources. It seems that there is a discussion in the links I pasted about the possible correction of this problem;

Comment: I've checked the links you providing. Obviously if you can't downgrade the `debug` version, you can only transpile the module manually. You could try to use Babel and Webpack to transpile it. You could check my update to the answer.